# BacklogLimitExceeded error with Celery, Django, RabbitMQ (or Redis) and RPC

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have a django application that needs to do sometimes millions of API requests. In order to make it faster, I'm using Celery to send the requests and wait for response before consuming them.

I have tried setting up Celery with Redis as a broker and a backend:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

That gave me an error: BacklogLimitExceeded: 54c6d0ce-318d-461b-b942-5edcd258b5f1

Then I changed to a RabbitMQ broker and RPC backend :

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Same error

My code for the API call is quite classic:

I have a list of `urls_chunks = [[url1, url2....url1000], [url1, url2....url1000]]` 
This is needed because of the API rate limit of 1000 per minute (at the end of each call group I sleep 1 minute)

```
for urls in urls_chunks:
    returned_data = []
    for url in urls:
        result = call_api.delay(url)
        returned_data.append(result)

for response in returned_data:
    result = response.result
    ## Do something with the result
    sleep(60)
```

I think all the url calls / responses are being cached somewhere and exceeding memory? but I thought that wouldn't happen with RPC. I thought of using a purge() but that does not work either as it is not supported by RPC...

Anyone know how to deal with this? I'm currently running in dev environment on MacOS, with the intention of deploying to Ubuntu.

Thanks!